# CkEditor: Image2 (enhanced image) plugin simplified upload process

Tags: user-interface, plugins, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I am in the process of integrating the [Image2 (enhanced image)](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/image2) plugin into my CkEditor.
My use case for this plugin is for allowing users to upload images from local machines to the server.
So far so good, but the default upload process of this plugin has some steps I would like to be able to skip.

For instance, whenever I click the Image button in the editor's toolbar, I'd like the uploader to automatically open the file browser instead of just popping up the standard file managed dialog.

Also, I would like for the upload process to be automatically started whenever the user choodses the image to upload (by default, the plugin requires a click on the "Upload it"/"Send it to the server" button). Actually, I would like to remove the "Upload it"/"Send it to the server" button entirely.
[image: Default plugin GUI]

Last but not least, I'd like the dialog to close automatically whenever an image is successfully uploaded.

Feels like almost a no-brainer to me, but I could not find anyone that actually managed to solve this situation, despite the fact that this kind of question has been asked many times around the net in recent years.

Can someone point me in the right direction? thank you.